# What am I doing wrong during the seasoning process of my cast iron skillet

Tags: cast-iron, seasoning-pans

I have read a lot of articles and watch several videos on how to season a cast-iron skillet. But the outcome I am getting is nothing like what I find online.

My cast iron skillet comes out with spotty marks which are a bit sticky. I've repeated the process twice but now I am doubtful about doing it one more time.  I am using canola oil and a convection oven at 450F, leaving the pan upside down for 1 hour.

Here is a photo of the results.
[image]

Comment: Sounds hot to me, maybe that causes thinning and beading. Or, was the it a spray oil with other agents? Shouldn't hurt anything to keep going and build on some more layers, imho. My experience is mostly outdoors, but lots of layers happen naturally from years of use.

Comment: How did you apply the canola oil?

Comment: If this a cast iron pan with a finish or texture on it?

Comment: @gdD It is a cast iron pan with a smooth finish. I had to clean up the pan with a brillo pad, soap, and some kosher salt to remove the oil and start all over again the seasoning process. It seemed that the cleanup job I did the first time, with just soap and the rough side of the sponge, was not enough and therefore it left some sort of the texture that then developed into what I shared on the photo. I had applied the canola oil by rubbing it with a paper towel but on the second try I used flaxseed oil rubbing it with a dish towel and the result is so much better now. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You're using way too much oil. "A thin coat" really means thin--apply a small amount of oil, spread it around, and wipe it ALL off, leaving nothing but the shine.

Comment: 100% agree ... that surface looks like when you have too much oil in the pan, it sorta beads up, and then doesn't quite fully cure where the beads of oil are.